# I want to place boxes of text and images on the corners of the path. How to do that?

Tags: javascript, html, css, path

I have defined a path over which a red dot moves on scrolling up and down. I want to place boxes of text and images on the corners of the path. So how do I go about doing that?

```js
function positionTheDot() {

  // What percentage down the page are we? 
  var scrollPercentage = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);

  // Get path length
  var path = document.getElementById("theMotionPath");
  var pathLen = path.getTotalLength();

  // Get the position of a point at <scrollPercentage> along the path.
  var pt = path.getPointAtLength(scrollPercentage * pathLen);

  // Position the red dot at this point
  var dot = document.getElementById("dot");
  dot.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + pt.x + "," + pt.y + ")");

};

// Update dot position when we get a scroll event.
window.addEventListener("scroll", positionTheDot);

// Set the initial position of the dot.
positionTheDot();
```

```css
.verylong {
  height: 2000px;
}

svg {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #333333;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 820 820" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <path d="M10 10 H 600 V 500 H 10 L 10 10" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="5" fill="none" id="theMotionPath"/>
     <!--<circle cx="10" cy="110" r="3" fill="#000"/>  <!--The bottom grey dot-->
        <!-- <circle cx="110" cy="10" r="3" fill="#000"/>  <!--The top grey dot-->
 
 

        <!-- Red circle which will be moved along the motion path. -->
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="red" id="dot"/>
 
    </svg>

<div class="verylong">
</div>
```

---

This is what I tried to do by adding div, I had added cx and cy in div but that didn't help.

```
    div {
            width: 320px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 5px solid gray;
            margin: 0;
     }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 120 120">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 820 820" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <path d="M10 10 H 600 V 500 H 10 L 10 10" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-
    width="5" fill="none" id="theMotionPath"/>  

        <!-- Red circle which will be moved along the motion path. -->
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="red" id="dot"/>

        <div>This text is the actual content of the box.</div>
    </svg>
```

Comment: @FrankerZ I tried using div but then the box came below the entire path.

Comment: Post that code, and we what your issue is, and we can help further.

Comment: @FrankerZ I have added the snippet now

Comment: What do you mean "didn't help"? What did it do, and what exactly are you looking for. Help us help you: Clarify what you've tried, tell us what didn't work. When you post "I tried x (No explanation), doesn't work", it makes it extremely difficult to diagnose and fix.

Comment: @FrankerZ by that I meant no changes were observed. It was the way it looked before. When I am putting in div and the coordinates, the box appears below the path again. Not what I want. I want the box of text to be on the corners of the path.